# Can't install Laravel Elixir with npm install in Vagrant environment

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-elixir

I installed Laravel with Scotch Box and I want to use **gulp** so I can automate some tasks but when I try to install Elixir with npm install I get the following output (created a gist, because it was too long to paste here): [npm install output](https://gist.github.com/ZiggyV/9f353a4a44ff8f2fa229).

The only thing that keeps returning in all my attempts to fix this error is this line:

> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.2

I already tried to use `npm install --no-bin-links` and I also tried to remove the node_modules folder from my project and run `npm cache clean` and then `npm install` again. Both of these methods didn't work either.

The only thing that works is `npm install bootstrap-sass`. This will install my bootstrap modules but when I try to install Elixir with `npm install laravel-elixir` I get the same error.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Node version in my VM

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ node -v
v4.0.0
```

Npm version

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ npm -v
2.14.8
```

Gulp version

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ gulp -v
[17:42:40] CLI version 3.9.0
[17:42:40] Local version 3.9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run npm install in your VM/scotchbox but run it on your local system instead to solve this. Start gulp from there and you're good to go.

Comment: That didn't work initially, only my gulp and bootstap modules would be installed. Only when I tried installing the specific module with `npm install laravel-elixir`, I would still get some warning and errors, but it would install properly and I could run `gulp`. Thanks!